# Exporting MBTiles from mapbox

Tags: mapbox, tilemill

Good day all 
I have stumbled on a pot of gold named Mapbox and in reading I came accross the line saying that you can"Export Studio sources as MBTiles files" Unfortunately I have not been able to find this function in Studio but I do see it in Tilemil. So i am assuming that MBTiles are to be created from tileMil.

However, I have my map designed already in Mapbox. Despite having seen the importing of the excel file, I am not seeing much options of importing it into tilemil to make an .MBTile out of it. I was hoping if someone could clarify the manner in which this is done.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you save your project then select settings on the left hand side and there should be an option to export to MBTiles, simples!